# Limit e Offset para paginação web em SQL Server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, select

Estou trabalhando com PHP e tenho cerca de 8000 registros atualmente no DB.

Como é para uma página web, preciso fazer uma paginação para ficar viável a leitura dos dados.

Pelo que eu entendi, eu tenho que fazer algo semelhante ao `limit` e `offset` para mostrar de 50 em 50 páginas, mas não sei como fazer isso com SQL Server.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que funcione com o Join abaixo:

```
select  os.id, 
        os.dataHora, 
        material.nome as nomeEquip, 
        cliente.nomeFantasia, 
        setor.nome as NomeSetor, 
        os.motivoOs, 

(select sum(itemMaterial.valorUnitario) from os as OS1 inner join
             itemMaterial on itemMaterial.id = os.idItemMaterial 
where OS1.id = os.id ) as TotalMaterial, 

tipoOs.nome as NomeTipoOS, itemMaterial.nSerie, itemMaterial.rm, os.status from os 
inner join itemMaterial on itemMaterial.id = os.idItemMaterial 
inner join modelo on modelo.id = itemMaterial.idModelo 
inner join material on material.id = itemMaterial.idMaterial 
inner join cliente on cliente.id = os.idCliente 
inner join setor on setor.id = os.idSetor 
inner join usuario on usuario.id = os.idUsuarioSolicitante 
inner join tipoOs on tipoOs.id = os.idTipoOs 

where cliente.id = (select usuario.idCliente from usuario where usuario.login = 'julio') 
order by dataHora desc
```

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/FabricioYwin/723219f1154c4573e9d60236b5f96134)

Como proceder neste caso?

Comment: Link util: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Fabricio poderia explicar um pouco melhor qual o resultado que quer obter? Ou você só quer saber o equivalente de Limit e Offset pra sql-server?

Comment: @Bacco.
Eu estou trabalhando com PHP e tenho 8.000 registros.
Já sabe como isso fica numa página web. Eu quero fazer uma paginação.
Pelo que eu entendi, eu tenho que fazer algo semelhante ao limit offset para mostrar de 50 em 50 páginas.

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de transpor isto para a pergunta ficar mais clara, dê uma conferida no histórico de alterações: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/168260/revisions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**A partir do SQL 2012**

```
SELECT coluna1,
       ...
  FROM tabela
 WHERE ...
 ORDER BY coluna1,
          ...
 OFFSET @Offset ROWS
 FETCH NEXT @Limit ROWS ONLY;
```

No seu caso você pode trocar a variável `@Limit` para `@QtdPorPagina` e `@Offset` para `(@Pagina - 1) * @QtdPorPagina` e utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @QtdPorPagina INT = 50,
        @Pagina       INT = 1;
```

**Substituindo na sua `query`**

```
DECLARE @QtdPorPagina INT = 50,
        @Pagina       INT = 1;

SELECT os.id,
       os.dataHora,
       material.nome AS nomeEquip,
       cliente.nomeFantasia,
       setor.nome AS NomeSetor,
       os.motivoOs,
       (SELECT SUM(itemMaterial.valorUnitario)
          FROM os AS OS1
               INNER JOIN itemMaterial ON itemMaterial.id = os.idItemMaterial
         WHERE OS1.id = os.id ) AS TotalMaterial,
       tipoOs.nome AS NomeTipoOS,
       itemMaterial.nSerie,
       itemMaterial.rm,
       os.status
  FROM os
       INNER JOIN itemMaterial ON itemMaterial.id = os.idItemMaterial
       INNER JOIN modelo ON modelo.id = itemMaterial.idModelo
       INNER JOIN material ON material.id = itemMaterial.idMaterial
       INNER JOIN cliente ON cliente.id = os.idCliente
       INNER JOIN setor ON setor.id = os.idSetor
       INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.id = os.idUsuarioSolicitante
       INNER JOIN tipoOs ON tipoOs.id = os.idTipoOs
 WHERE cliente.id = (SELECT usuario.idCliente
                       FROM usuario
                      WHERE usuario.login = 'julio')
 ORDER BY dataHora DESC
OFFSET (@Pagina - 1) * @QtdPorPagina ROWS
 FETCH NEXT @QtdPorPagina ROWS ONLY;
```

---

**Para SQL Server anterior ao 2012**

Para obter um resultado parecido você pode utilizar a função `ROW_NUMBER()`para gerar o número da linha e trabalhar com essa informação da seguinte forma:

```
WITH resultado AS
(SELECT coluna1,
        ...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY coluna1, ...) AS linha
   FROM tabela
  WHERE ...)
SELECT *
  FROM resultado
 WHERE linha >= @Offset
   AND linha < @Offset + @Limit
```

---

**Pergunta semelhante do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/): [Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server)**

Comment: Me parece que funcionou.
Eu só vou ter que trabalhar isso no php pq a quantidade de registros vai depender do filtro.
Penso que eu vou ter que pegar o count = limit e trabalhar o offset

Comment: @fabricio_wm Pelo `PHP` mesmo você pode substituir as variáveis `@QtdPorPagina` e `@Pagina`

Comment: Sim.
Como eu testo a paginação no sql server?
Eu altero o valor da @pagina e o resultado permanece o mesmo.

Comment: @fabricio_wm Você fez a substituição  como eu recomendei no final da resposta? Porque eu testei aqui e funcionou mudando o `@Pagina`

Comment: @fabricio_wm adicionei o exemplo completo a sua `query`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/FabricioYwin/723219f1154c4573e9d60236b5f96134

Olha pelo link, pfv.

Comment: @fabricio_wm Você colocou `@Pagina - 3` sendo que **sempre** será `@Pagina - 1`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49229/discussion-between-fabricio-wm-and-sorack).

Comment: @fabricio_wm poderia colocar como ficou seu código?