# Selecionar registros a partir de um registro a outro no sql server

Tags: sql, select, servidor

Quero fazer um select, do registro 20 até a 50 no SQL SERVER, mas não estou conseguindo!

Estou usando assim:

```
SELECT * FROM table OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Mas não funciona!

Sei que tem o: TOP 10
Que vai listar da linha 0 até a 10

Comment: Pode pf colocar a consulta que está a utilizar? Sei que a questão até pode ser simples, mas se não nos der mais informação será difícil darmos respostas válidas.

Comment: Estou usando assim: 

SELECT * FROM table OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY

Mas não funciona!

Sei que tem o: TOP 10
Que vai listar da linha 0 até a 10

Comment: Qual a sua versão do `SQL Server`?

Comment: Versão 2008 do SQL Server

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Limit e Offset para paginação web em SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168260/limit-e-offset-para-pagina%c3%a7%c3%a3o-web-em-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso basta utilizar o [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS Linha
                ,   *
            FROM    tabela
        ) X
WHERE   X.Linha BETWEEN 10 AND 50
```

A coluna `id` deverá ser a coluna de ordenação que pretende para "criar" a numeração sequencial das linhas.

Comment: essa linha eu editei minha pergunta, linha seria o registro, ou seja, selecionar o registro da posição 10 até a 50.

Comment: E essa consulta que coloquei devolve-lhe os registos da linha 10 à 50. É isso que pretende, certo? Pode sempre colocar a estrutura da sua tabela para ter uma resposta mais correta (e real).

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe `OFFSET/FETCH NEXT` só está disponível a partir do `SQL Server 2012`. Ao invés de utilizá-la, crie uma `query` que irá retornar todos os seus dados em conjunto com a função `ROW_NUMBER` que irá atribuir um inteiro sequencial a cada linha permitindo que você selecione apenas os registros na posição desejada:

```
WITH resultado AS
(SELECT coluna1,
        ...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY coluna1, ...) AS linha
   FROM tabela
  WHERE ...)
SELECT *
  FROM resultado
 WHERE linha >= 20
   AND linha < 50
```

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, iniciando em 1 para a primeira linha de cada partição.

Comment: linha seria a coluna? Eu editei minha pergunta, acho que ficou confuso...seria do registro 10 até o 50 da tabela.

Comment: @user3081 linha é um identificador gerado. Seria o número da linha

Comment: Fiz teste com esse modelo no Navicat Sql Server, mas deu erro. Eu alterei a tabela, e retirei as colunas, pois quero selecionar tudo que tem nela.

Comment: @user3081 você tem que fazer o `OVER` em cima da coluna de id dele, sem isso sua `query` não vai rodar. Sem saber a estrutura da sua tabela não consigo te ajudar mais que isso

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Amigão tente da seguinte maneira.

```
USE vendateste
GO

WITH TesteVenda AS
--Nesse Sub Select uso o  ROW_NUMBER Para numerar a saída do conjunto do resultado 
(
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdContrato ASC) AS RowNumber,
        IdContrato, DataBaseContrato    
    FROM Venda 
)
--Aqui trago os dados do meu sub select
SELECT
        IdContrato, 
        DataBaseContrato,
        RowNumber
    FROM TesteVenda
    --Aqui seleciono as linhas que eu quero no meu resultado
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 10 and 20
```

> ROW_NUMBER
>
> Numera a saída de um conjunto de resultados. Mais especificamente,
>   retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um
>   conjunto de resultados, começando em 1 na primeira linha de cada
>   partição.

Documentação:[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)