# Sql server herança em procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

Estou tendo problemas de performance em usar *views* mapeadas no *EF* para poder usar `linq` para agrupamentos e paginação. Teria uma forma de montar uma `procedure` base, onde eu explicitasse o que seria necessário para que todas as `procedures` filhas implementassem?

Ou alguma forma de *template*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, Gilmar. Tudo bem?

A princípio você poderia verificar se a criação de índices pode melhorar a performance das suas views, caso não tem visto ainda. Outra forma de resolver é materializar os dados da views em tabelas físicas, mas pode acabar ocupando bastante espaço.

Em relação a sua última pergunta, é possível montar essa estrutura sim. Você pode criar uma procedure (base) que tenha um `output`, e, a partir desta saída alimentar o parâmetro das demais variáveis. Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
-- Declare the variable to receive the output value of the procedure.  
DECLARE @SalesYTDBySalesPerson money;  
-- Execute the procedure specifying a last name for the input parameter  
-- and saving the output value in the variable @SalesYTDBySalesPerson 

EXECUTE Sales.spGetEmployeeSalesExemplo_Base  
    N'Blythe', @SalesYTD = @SalesYTDBySalesPerson OUTPUT;  

--Executando a procedure (Filha) com o parametro retornado da procedure base 
EXECUTE Sales.spSalesExemplo_Filha @SalesPerson = @SalesYTDBySalesPerson;  
GO
```

Para mais detalhes você pode verificar a documentação de onde eu adaptei o código: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15

Lembrando que, esta é apenas uma das formas de solucionar o problema. Uma segunda alternativa seria a procedure base "alimentar"/popular uma tabela com os parâmentros que vão ser usados/consumidos pelas procedures filhas.

Caso precise de ajuda para montar a solução, pode me contatar. Ficarei feliz em poder ajudar.

Abs.,
Welricsson Carmo

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas acho que não vai resolver, porque eu encontrei essa limitação lá:
'A nonscrollable cursor is opened in a procedure on a result set named RS of 100 rows'.
Pensando que uma procedure seria a consulta em si a outra seria a paginação, a responsável pela paginação não pode receber somente 100 linhas, precisava receber a 'consulta completa' e ela definir o top 10 (por exemplo).

Comment: Entendi. É algo bem específico. Eu teria que ver no detalhe pra saber o que fazer. Encontrei algo similar aqui no Stackoverflow. Veja se te ajuda de alguma forma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168260/limit-e-offset-para-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web-em-sql-server